# Python string formatting - Possible use of lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, string-formatting

I'm doing some formatted table printing, and I was wondering how i could do something like this, I think it's a situation for lambda, but I've never used it before so I'm not sure :)

```
print "{:^{}}|"*(self.size).format(for i in range(self.size),6) 
# self size is assumed to be 5 in this example, doesn't work, something along this line is needed though
```

Basically, do this(below) but in a cleaner way. PS. i know the below example doesn't work, but you get my drift

```
print "{:^{}}" * 5 .format(humangrid[0][0],4,humangrid[0][1],4,humangrid[0][2],4,humangrid[0][3],4,humangrid[0][4],4,
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would be useful if you can share some example data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess:

```
print '|'.join('{:^6}'.format(i) for i in range(self.size))
...
print ''.join('{:^4}'.format(i) for i in humangrid[0])
```

If you really want to do it with a single call to `string.format()`:

```
print '|'.join(['{:^6}'*self.size]).format(*range(self.size))
...
print ('{:^4}'*len(humangrid[0])).format(*humangrid[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to pring a 2d list of names in a centered tabular way, here's one way to do it:

```
humangrid = [
    ["john", "jacob", "jezebel"],
    ["mary", "maria", "mel"],
    ["shareen", "sean", "shiva"],
]

cell_width = max(len(y) for x in humangrid for y in x)  # get length of longest name
cell_width += 2  # optional padding

for row in humangrid:
    print "|".join(name.center(cell_width) for name in row)
```

Running that will give you:

```
   john  |  jacob  | jezebel 
   mary  |  maria  |   mel   
 shareen |   sean  |  shiva
```

To change the alignment of the table, simply replace [`center()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.center) with [`ljust()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ljust) or [`rjust()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rjust).

One can quite easily replace that to use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), but I find this approach a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you mean

```
print(("{:4}|"*len(humangrid[0])).format(*humangrid[0]))
```

The idea is just using `format(*xxx)` for calling format with a variable number of arguments.